# Complex Search in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is an unusual and difficult question which has perplexed me for a number of days and I hope I explain it correctly. I have two databases i.e. data-frames in R, the first is approx 90,000 rows and is a record of every race-horse in the UK. It contains numerous fields, and most importantly the NAME of each horse and its SIRE; one record per horse [First database, sample and fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HPK4.png).  The second database contains over one-million rows and is a history of every race a horse has taken part in over the last ten years i.e. races it has run or as I call it 'appearances', it contains NAME, DATE, TRACK etc..; one record per appearance.[Second database, sample and fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGTCD.png)

What I am attempting to do is to write a few lines of code - not a loop - that will provide me with a total number of every appearance made by the siblings **of a particular horse**  i.e. one grand total. The first step is easy - finding the siblings i.e. horses with a common sire - and you can see it below (N.B FindSire is my own function which does what it says and finds the sire of a horse by referencing the same dataframe. I have  simplified the code somewhat for clarity)

```
 TestHorse <- "Save The Bees"

 Siblings <- which(FindSire(TestHorse) == Horses$Sire)

 Sibsname <- Horses[sibs,1]
```

The produces Sibsname which is a 636 names long (snippet below), although the average horse will only have 50 or so siblings. I could construct a loop and search the second 'appearances' data-frame and individually match the sibling names and then total the appearances of all the siblings combined. However, I would like to know if I could avoid a loop - and the time associated with it - and write a few lines of code to achieve the same end i.e. search all 636 horses in the appearances database and  calculate the times each appears in the  database and a total of all these appearances, or to put it another way, how many races have the siblings of "save the bees" taken part in. Thanks in advance.

```
 [1] "abdication "         "aberdonian "         "acclamatory "        "accolation "  ..... to [636]
```

Comment: Please see this link to learn how to provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, calling your "first database" `horses` and your "second database" `races`:

```
library(dplyr)
test_horse = "Save The Bees"

select(horses, Name, Sire) %>%
  filter(Sire == Sire[Name == tolower(test_horse)]) %>%
  inner_join(races, c("Name" = "SELECTION_NAME")) %>%
  summarize(horse = test_horse, sibling_group_races = n())
```

I am making the assumption that you want the number of appearances of the sibling group to include the appearances of the test horse - to omit them instead add `, Name != tolower(test_horse)` to the `filter()` command.

As you haven't shared data reproducibly, I cannot test the code. If you have additional problems I will not be able to help you solve them unless you *share data reproducibly*. ycw's comment has a helpful link for doing that - I would encourage you to edit your question to include either (a) code to simulate a small sample of data, or (b) use `dput()` on an small sample of your data to share a few rows in a copy/pasteable format.

The code above will do for querying one horse at a time - if you intend to use it frequently it would be much simpler to just create a table where each row represents a sibling group and contains the number of races. Then you could just reference the table instead of calculating on the fly every time. That would look like this:

```
sibling_appearances = 
  left_join(horses, races, by = c("Name" = "SELECTION_NAME")) %>%
  group_by(Sire) %>%
  summarize(offspring_appearances = n())
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. Sorry, I did not have sufficient data for you to check the result but I am new to posting questions - but will do so for the next question I post.  The 'index' was what I was actually looking for as you correctly surmised. I have one index already for another portion of the code but it was generated by a series of loops which was too slow.